# WP8 - Live Tile Icon Color

Tags: windows-phone-8, live-tile

How do I set the color of the main icon of a live tile in a Windows Phone app? By default Windows Phone 8 sets it to a black and white.

I want to set the icon to a color like red, similar to how the [Evernote](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/evernote/db21927d-f292-e011-986b-78e7d1fa76f8) tile has its icon in gray. Anyone knows how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The documentation provides info about this: [**Iconic Tile template for Windows Phone 8**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207009(v=vs.105).aspx)

**XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification" Version="2.0">
  <wp:Tile Id="[Tile ID]" Template="IconicTile">
    <wp:SmallIconImage [Action="Clear"]>[small Tile size URI]</wp:SmallIconImage>
    <wp:IconImage Action="Clear">[medium/wide Tile size URI]</wp:IconImage>
    <wp:WideContent1 Action="Clear">[1st row of content]</wp:WideContent1>
    <wp:WideContent2 Action="Clear">[2nd row of content]</wp:WideContent2>
    <wp:WideContent3 Action="Clear">[3rd row of content]</wp:WideContent3>
    <wp:Count Action="Clear">[count]</wp:Count>
    <wp:Title Action="Clear">[title]</wp:Title>
    <wp:BackgroundColor Action="Clear">[hex ARGB format color]</wp:BackgroundColor>
  </wp:Tile>
</wp:Notification>
```

**C#**

```
IconicTileData TileData = new IconicTileData()
{
    Title = "[title]",
    Count = [count],
    WideContent1 = "[1st row of content]",
    WideContent2 = "[2nd row of content]",
    WideContent3 = "[3rd row of content]",
    SmallIconImage = [small Tile size URI],
    IconImage = [medium/wide Tile size URI],
    BackgroundColor = [.NET color type of Tile]
};
```